# How to return specific data from json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, duedil-api

I'm accessing data from an API using json_decode. The code I have returns the array of ALL the date (see below), but I want to return specific data such as 'name' or 'locale'.

```
$json_string = 'http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q=Surfing%20Sumo&api_key=THE-API-KEY';
          $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
          $obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
          echo '<pre>';
          var_dump($obj);
```

This is what is returned (this is abbreviated to save space here):

```
array(1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["pagination"]=>
    string(79) "http://api.duedil.com/open/search?query=Duedil&total_results=6&limit=5&offset=5"
    ["data"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["company_number"]=>
        string(8) "06999618"
        ["locale"]=>
        string(14) "United Kingdom"
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Duedil Limited"
        ["uri"]=>
        string(51) "http://api.duedil.com/open/uk/company/06999618.json"
      }
```

Comment: you have to get the `locale` or `name` from this returned array.

Comment: FYI: we're building new API https://www.duedil.com/api/docs so soon you'd be able to use this new version that will allow you to generate a PHP client using Swagger specification. That should save you a lot of time on the integration side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use

```
$name = $obj['response']['data'][0]['name'];
$locale = $obj['response']['data'][0]['locale'];
```

if you have multiple return values, you could loop over them

```
foreach ($obj['response']['data'] as $item) {
    $name = $item['name'];
    $locale = $item['locale'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorted!

Answer (score 1):

try this sample code:

```
 <?php
$data =  isset($obj['response']['data'])?$obj['response']['data']:FALSE;

if(is_array($data))
{
   foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo $value['name'];
    echo $value['locale'];
} 
}
```